# C: How do you read and unpack a message over a socket?

Tags: c, sockets, buffer, unpack

I am trying to receive an updated message over the socket and unpack the
data. I want to use the update_client function to update the server's
internal representation of the client co-ordinates and respond to the
client with the required value.

I think I should use recv to read the full message (of length UPDATE_CMD_LEN) into buffer.

Then unpack data having message in the following format:

```
      U<id><fields of gpscoords>
```

Character 'U' (meaning update), followed by ID of the client (unsigned char)
and then the gpscoord structure in network format.

This is a rough idea of how to do it but I don't know how:

[1] Unpack ID

[2] Unpack coordinates with `int update_client(unsigned char id, gpscoords *pos`
which takes ID and pointer to position struct, returns -1 on error and 0 on success

The server should then respond to client using sendto function and reply
NO_RES on error and SUCC_RES on success.

```
void do_update(int sockfd, struct sockaddr_in *clientaddr) {
    char msg[UPDATE_CMD_LEN];

    recv(sockfd, msg, UPDATE_CMD_LEN, flags);

    fprintf(stderr, "do_update not implemented!\n");
    exit(-1);
}
```

client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "gps.h"

#define CMD_LEN  10
#define LINE_LEN NAME_LEN + 15

#define FIREFOX "/usr/bin/firefox"


void make_route_url(char *url, gpscoords *pos, gpscoords *target) {
    char pos_sign_n;
    char pos_sign_e;
    char tar_sign_n;
    char tar_sign_e;

    pos_sign_n = pos->north ? '+' : '-';
    pos_sign_e = pos->east ? '+' : '-';
    tar_sign_n = target->north ? '+' : '-';
    tar_sign_e = target->east ? '+' : '-';

    sprintf(url,
            "http://map.project-osrm.org/?z=13&loc=%c%u.%u,%c%u.%u&loc=%c%u.%u,%c%u.%u",
            pos_sign_n, pos->lat, pos->lat_frac,
            pos_sign_e, pos->lon, pos->lon_frac,
            tar_sign_n, target->lat, target->lat_frac,
            tar_sign_e, target->lon, target->lon_frac);
}

void show_route(gpscoords *pos, gpscoords *target) {

    // char url[75];

    fprintf(stderr, "show_route not implemented!\n");
    exit(-1);
}



int run_client(char *name, char *serverip) {
    char *cmdline;
    size_t line_len;
    char cmd[11];
    gpsinfo info;
    gpscoords pos, targetpos;
    char targetname[NAME_LEN];

    bzero(targetname, NAME_LEN);
    bzero(&info, sizeof(info));
    bzero(&pos, sizeof(pos));
    bzero(&targetpos, sizeof(targetpos));

    if (register_client(serverip, name, &info) == -1) {
        perror("Error registering client.");
        return -1;
    }

    find_self(&pos);
    if (update_position(&info, &pos) == -1) {
        printf("Failed to send initial position to server.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    for (;;) {
        printf("Command: ");
        line_len = 0;
        cmdline = NULL;
        getline(&cmdline, &line_len, stdin);

        if (strncmp(cmdline, "update", 3) == 0) {
            find_self(&pos);
            if (update_position(&info, &pos) == -1) {
                printf("Failed to update.\n");
            }
        } else if (strncmp(cmdline, "find", 3) == 0) {
            sscanf(cmdline, "%10s %25s", cmd, targetname);
            if (get_position(&info, targetname, &targetpos) == -1) {
                printf("Couldn't find target.\n");
            } else {
                show_route(&pos, &targetpos);
            }
        } else if (strncmp(cmdline, "quit", 4) == 0) {
            free(cmdline);
            break;
        }
        free(cmdline);
    }

    if (unregister_client(&info) == -1) {
        perror("Error unregistering client.");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: ./client <client name> <server_ip>\n");
        return 0;
    }

    return run_client(argv[1], argv[2]);
}
```

socket.c

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "sockets.h"


int create_dg_socket(in_port_t port) {

    // Create the socket

    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        printf("create_dg_socket cannot create socket!");
        return -1;
    }

    // Bind the socket port

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0) {
        printf("create_dg_socket cannot bind socket!");
        close(sockfd);
        return -1;
    }

    return sockfd;
}


int open_dg_socket(char *ipaddr, in_port_t port, struct sockaddr_in *addr) {

    // Create the socket

    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        return -1;
    }

    // Setup

    addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr->sin_port = htons(port);
    addr->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipaddr);

    return sockfd;
}


int dg_sendrecv(int sockfd,

                struct sockaddr_in *addr,
                char *message, size_t out_len,
                char *response, size_t in_len) {

    if (sendto(sockfd, message, out_len, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(*addr)) == -1) {
        printf("dg_sendrecv cannot send data!");
        return -1;
    }

    int ret = recvfrom(sockfd, response, in_len, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (ret == -1) {
        printf("dg_sendrecv cannot read data!");
        return -1;
    }

    return ret;
}

/*
int dg_sendrecv(int sockfd,
                struct sockaddr_in *addr,
                char *message, size_t out_len,
                char *response, size_t in_len) {

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipaddr);

    return dg_sendrecv_addr(sockfd, &addr, message, out_len, response, in_len);

}
*/
```

server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "sockets.h"
#include "gps.h"
#include "server.h"

#define NUM_CLIENTS 5

char clients[NUM_CLIENTS][NAME_LEN];
gpscoords coords[NUM_CLIENTS];



void do_register(int sockfd, struct sockaddr_in *clientaddr) {
    char msg[REGISTER_CMD_LEN];
    char *name;
    unsigned char id, i;

    if (recv(sockfd, msg, REGISTER_CMD_LEN, 0) == -1) {
        perror("Error receiving register command.");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // first byte is server command, rest is name
    name = &msg[1];

    id = NO_RES;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_CLIENTS; ++i) {
        if (clients[i][0] == '\0') {
            strncpy(clients[i], name, NAME_LEN);
            clients[i][NAME_LEN - 1] = '\0';
            bzero(&coords[i], sizeof(coords[i]));
            id = i + 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (sendto(sockfd, 
               &id, sizeof(id), 
               0,
               (struct sockaddr *)clientaddr, sizeof(*clientaddr)) == -1) {
        perror("Error replying to client.");
        exit(-1);
    }
}

void do_unregister(int sockfd, struct sockaddr_in *clientaddr) {
    unsigned char msg[UNREGISTER_CMD_LEN];
    unsigned char id;
    char res = NO_RES;

    if (recv(sockfd, &msg, UNREGISTER_CMD_LEN, 0) == -1) {
        perror("Error receiving unregister command.");
        exit(-1);
    }

    id = msg[1] - 1;
    if (id < NUM_CLIENTS) {
        clients[id][0] = '\0';
        res = SUCC_RES;
    }

    if (sendto(sockfd, 
               &res, sizeof(res), 
               0, 
               (struct sockaddr *)clientaddr, sizeof(*clientaddr)) == -1) {
        perror("Error responding to client.");
        exit(-1);
    }
}

int update_client(unsigned char id, gpscoords *pos) {
    id -= 1;
    if (id >= NUM_CLIENTS)
        return -1;
    memcpy(&coords[id], pos, sizeof(coords[id]));
    return 0;
}


void do_update(int sockfd, struct sockaddr_in *clientaddr) {
    /**
     * Receive an update message over the socket and unpack the
     * data.  Then use the update_client function to update the server's
     * internal representation of the client co-ordinates.  Then respond to the
     * client with the required value.
     * Use recv to read the full message (of length UPDATE_CMD_LEN) into buffer.
     * Unpack data, message of following format:
     *           U<id><fields of gpscoords>
     * Character 'U' (meaning update), followed by ID of the client (unsigned char)
     * and then the gpscoord structure in network format.
     *
     * 1. Unpack ID
     * 2. Unpack coordinates with (int update_client(unsigned char id, gpscoords *pos)
     * which takes ID and pointer to position struct, returns -1 on error and 0 on success
     * Server should then respond to client using sendto function and reply
     * NO_RES on error and SUCC_RES on success.
     */

    char msg[UPDATE_CMD_LEN];

    recv(sockfd, msg, UPDATE_CMD_LEN, flags);

    fprintf(stderr, "do_update not implemented!\n");
    exit(-1);
}

static gpscoords *get_client(char *name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CLIENTS; ++i) {
        if (strcmp(name, clients[i]) == 0) {
            return &coords[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void do_get(int sockfd, struct sockaddr_in *clientaddr) {
    char msg[GET_CMD_LEN];
    char res[GET_RES_LEN];
    char *name;

    if (recv(sockfd, msg, GET_CMD_LEN, 0) == -1) {
        perror("Error receiving get command.");
        exit(-1);
    }

    name = &msg[1];
    name[NAME_LEN - 1] = '\0';

    gpscoords *pos = get_client(name);
    if (pos == NULL) {
        res[0] = NO_RES;
    } else {
        res[0] = SUCC_RES;
        pack_gpscoords(pos, &res[1]);
    }

    if (sendto(sockfd, 
               &res, GET_RES_LEN, 
               0, 
               (struct sockaddr *)clientaddr, sizeof(*clientaddr)) == -1) {
        perror("Error sending result to client.");
        exit(-1);
    }
}



int serve(int sockfd) {
    char cmd;
    struct sockaddr_in clientaddr;
    socklen_t clientaddrlen = sizeof(clientaddr);

    for (;;) {
        if (recvfrom(sockfd, 
                     &cmd, sizeof(cmd), 
                     MSG_PEEK,
                     (struct sockaddr *)&clientaddr, &clientaddrlen) == -1) {
            exit(-1);
        }

        switch (cmd) {
        case CMD_REGISTER:
            do_register(sockfd, &clientaddr);
            break;
        case CMD_UNREGISTER:
            do_unregister(sockfd, &clientaddr);
            break;
        case CMD_UPDATE:
            do_update(sockfd, &clientaddr);
            break;
        case CMD_GET:
            do_get(sockfd, &clientaddr);
            break;
        default: 
            break;
        }
    }
}


void init_info() {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_CLIENTS; ++i) {
        clients[i][0] = '\0';
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int sockfd = create_dg_socket(SERVER_PORT);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating socket!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    init_info();

    printf("Server ready.\n");

    serve(sockfd);

    // Note: server never terminates, we're relying on the system to clean up
    // our open socket file descriptor (and shut it down)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @chqrlie any tips? :)

Comment: I cannot see what protocol/s you are using.

Comment: @MartinJames it's a datagram socket

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to safe and read data from char arrays that maybe will help you:

```
char buffer[5+sizeof(gpscoords)];
int *int_pointer;
gpscoords *gps_pointer;

int id=1;
gpscoords gps="some gps contend";

int id_frombuffer;
gpscoords gps_frombuffer;
char c_frombuffer;

buffer[0]='U';

int_pointer=(int*)&buffer;
int_pointer+=1;
*int_pointer=id;

gps_pointer=(gpscoords*)&buffer;
gps_pointer+=5;
*gpspointer=gps;

//send buffer


c_frombuffer=buffer[0];//c_frombuffer now contains 'U'

int_pointer=(int*)&buffer;
int_pointer+=1;
id_frombuffer=*int_pointer;//id_frombuffer now contains 1

gps_pointer=(gpscoords*)&buffer;
gpscoords+=5;
gps_frombuffer=*pointer;//gps_frombuffer now contains "some gps contend"
```

As an example if your client code looks like that:

```
void sendupdate(unsigned char id,gpscoords gps)
{
    char buffer[2+sizeof(gpscoords)];
    gpscoords *gps_pointer;

    buffer[0]='U';
    buffer[1]=id;

    gps_pointer=(gpscoords*)&buffer;
    gps_pointer+=2;
    *gpspointer=gps;
    send(socket, buffer, 2+sizeof(gpscoords), flags);
}
```

your server function should look like that:

```
void do_update(int sockfd, struct sockaddr_in *clientaddr)
{
    char buffer[2+sizeof(gpscoords)];

    recv(sockfd, buffer, 2+sizeof(gpscoords), flags);

    unsigned char id_frombuffer=buffer[1];

    gpscoords *gpspointer=(gpscoords*)&buffer;
    gpspointer+=2;

    update_client(id_frombuffer, gpspointer);

}
```

Comment: how can I implement this to my do_update method though?

Comment: can you show us the client code sending the buffer?

Comment: sorry my fault i mean the part off the code were you send the buffer you receive in the 'void do_update()' method. We cannot help you to unpack data if we dont know how its packed.

Comment: server.c and client.c are the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106846/discussion-between-iona-and-phathe).

Comment: it was a mistake, check again